# How to pass multiple ArrayList<String> to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to pass three arrays to other activity, but for whatever reason it seems like only one last array passed from the parent activity goes to the child and the rest dont
Here is the parent activity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_list_items);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    categoryTitle = intent.getStringExtra(categoryName);

    if(Arrays.asList(FragmentHelper.Days).contains(categoryTitle)) {
        header.setText("Start the workout");
        addButton.setText("Start");
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivityCopy.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                List<ListItem> items = listManager.getList(categoryTitle);
                ArrayList<String> itemName = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> itemTime = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> itemNumberOfSets = new ArrayList<>();

                for(int i = 0; i < listManager.getNumberOfItemsCopy(categoryTitle); i++) {
                    itemName.add(items.get(i).getDescription());
                    itemTime.add(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getTime()));
                    itemNumberOfSets.add(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getNumberOfSets()));
                }
                Log.d("Title:", itemName.toString());
                Log.d("Time:", itemTime.toString());
                Log.d("Num of sets:", itemNumberOfSets.toString());
                extras.putStringArrayList(ItemDetailActivityCopy.itemName.toString(), itemName);
                extras.putStringArrayList(ItemDetailActivityCopy.itemTime.toString(), itemTime);
                extras.putStringArrayList(ItemDetailActivityCopy.itemNumberOfSets.toString(), itemNumberOfSets);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an ArrayList<String> to another activity and convert it into double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640669/how-to-pass-an-arrayliststring-to-another-activity-and-convert-it-into-double)

Comment: "the rest dont" -- how have you determined this? Where is your code for retrieving values from the extras? Note that the keys to your extras are rather strange. Usually, we use constants, not `toString()` of some other object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing and ArrayList<Service> through intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014704/passing-and-arraylistservice-through-intent)

Answer (score 0):

pass `ArrayList<String>` from one `Activity` to other `Activity`,using `putStringArrayListExtra`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivityCopy.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("LIST_ITEMS", itemName);
startActivity(intent);
```

get `ArrayList<String>` from other Activity,

```
ArrayList<String> listItems;
listItems = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("LIST_ITEMS");
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how this would solve the problem.

Comment: I have explained in detail, use method of my answer to send & get ArrayList of String from one Activity to other

Comment: yep, it works, but i dont get why it did not when i         Bundle extras = new Bundle();

Comment: one more thing, how can i pass a Long array instead of string?

Comment: `putExtra` method with `long[]` value

Comment: if i do intent.putExtra("itemTime", itemTime); Then in child  long [] time;   time = intent.getLongArrayExtra("itemTime"); I get null

Comment: What is type of `itemTime`? if it's different then it will return null